# Exclude last column of a DataGridView from selection

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, datagridview

I am trying to get a list of all the columns name of a `DataGridView` except the last one.

The following returns all the columns:

```
var columnsList = datagridview.Columns
            .Cast<DataGridViewColumn>()
            .Select(c => c.Name);
```

I tried to use `Except` in order to remove the last column for the returned value:

```
 var columnsList = datagridview.Columns
            .Cast<DataGridViewColumn>()
            .Select(c => c.Name)
            .Except((datagridview.Columns.GetLastColumn(DataGridViewElementStates.Visible, DataGridViewElementStates.Visible).Name));
```

I am getting an error that `IEnumerable<string>` does not contain a definition for `Except`.

How can achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can exclude the last column by [*taking*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) only `n-1` columns :

```
var columnsList = datagridview.Columns
                              .Cast<DataGridViewColumn>()
                              .Take(datagridview.Columns.Count-1)
                              .Select(c => c.Name);
```

Answer (score 1):

`Except` requires a collection as input argument. It is a set operation: set1 minus set2. So *technically*, it should be

```
var lastColumn = datagridview.Columns.GetLastColumn(DataGridViewElementStates.Visible, DataGridViewElementStates.Visible).Name;
var columnsList = datagridview.Columns
            .Cast<DataGridViewColumn>()
            .Select(c => c.Name)
            .Except(new[] { lastColumn });
```

But of course, as already answered, it's much easier to use `Take(n-1)`, where `n` is the number of columns.

Comment: Thanks for giving the syntax. Indeed, Take is much elegant.

Answer (score 1):

get a list of all the columns name of a DataGridView except the last one  = 
take first `datagridview.Columns.Count - 1` columns

since `Columns` has an indexer and only implements `IEnumerable` (non-generic) I would use `Enumerable.Range` here

```
var names = Enumerable.Range(0, datagridview.Columns.Count - 1)
                      .Select(idx => datagridview.Columns[idx].Name);
```

Comment: Thank you, very nice solution too.